# Snort Error Cannot decode data link type 113

Tags: rules, snort, ids, ips

I am working on a little project and I have came across an error when I try to run snort. I went into snort.conf and changed my HOME_NET ip address to the address of the virtual machine since it will be acting as a DHCP server and I want to monitor traffic coming into it. I also commented out all snort rule files that were pre-added. I wanted the only rules used to be my snort local.rules file. In this file I wrote a log, alert, and drop rule.

I verified that my snort.conf was accurate by validating it with a test but when i go to actually run snort, I am presented with the error "Cannot decode data link type 113". I am not sure what the solution is. I checked around on google but could not find any solutions.